# How can I use a resource file (*.rc) to style a dialog-based application

Tags: windows, winapi, rc, createwindow

How can I use a resource file (*.rc) to style a dialog-based application?

I can use `CreateWindow` or `CreateWindowEx` to create the main window of an application. And some of the arguments of `CreateWindow` or `CreateWindowEx` define the styles of a dialogbox. But I want to style it using resource file (*.rc) instead of the way of by pass style arguments to function.

Could someone give me some snippets?

Someobody said I can call `DialogBox`, and give second argument the the style template.  Does this create a confict between `CreateWindow` and the *.rc file?  Or can I use both of them at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CreateDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645434%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). It handles wrapping the call to CreateWindowEx as well as posting the WM_INITDLG and WM_SETFONT messages if needed. There's an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644996%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#modeless_box) linked from the docs on MSDN.

You can get information about the content of the resource file here in the documentation for [DialogEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381002%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Start a new Win32 Project and let it auto-generate the code.  Change the WinMain function to look like this:

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), NULL, About);
    return 0;
}
```

You may want to add a call to MoveWindow() in the WM_INITDIALOG message handler to move the window to a better spot on the screen.